# In CSS, is there any way to add a tab break between two strings in `content`?

Tags: css, text, tabs, special-characters, pseudo-element

In CSS, is there any way to add a tab break between two strings in `content` like `\00a0` for an nbsp?

For example, you can write:

```
div.test::before {
   content: "hello\00a0world";
}
```

to output `hello world`.

But what about something that would output the word `hello` separated by a tab before the word `world`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also define the white-space algorithm

```css
div.test::before {
   content: "hello\09world";
   white-space:pre;
}

div.test2::before {
   content: "hello\Aworld";
   white-space:pre;
}

[class] {
  border:1px solid;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
</div>

<div class="test2">
</div>
```

Comment: Ah!  That's what I was missing!  Thank you so much!  Note that your first example works when I use 'Run code snippet' in Firefox, but the second one causes the two strings to appear on two separate lines.  Any idea why?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I used two unicodes to illustrate, one to create the tab (like you want) and another to create a line break. Wanted to show that whataver the *space* you try to add, you need to adjust white-space

Comment: Ah! I see what you did now and why you did it! Thank you so much for the explanation.